# How can I edit photoshop's open & save dialogue to put JPEG first?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, plugins, jpeg

It's just always bugged me. The one format everyone uses most... is halfway down a list of 20 file formats. I want jpeg at the top, and while we're at it let's just file GIF under "G" instead of under "C" (for 'compuserve gif').

I'd settle for removing all the unwanted formats like PSB or SCB.

So I need to get the photoshop SDK and hassle with visual studio? Has someone made a plugin to hide or rearrange there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue with png files, and I don't really want to go through the hassle of export-for-web dialog.

Here's the solution: http://www.formatscustomizer.com/

Comment: this looks EXACTLY like what I wanted, and works for other programs too. Fantastic. Sadly their website appears to be dead but I found what an alternate - http://www.tucows.com/preview/614646/Formats-Customizer . Cheers!

Comment: edit: aggHHhFG 32-bit only. Thanks anyway. Hope this project isn't abandoned, it's a fantastic idea.

Comment: edit 2: It seems the 32-bit app CAN work on a 64-bit system, after all. @vjkatt thanks so much again. Those who want to install this, bear in mind it will try to install some kind of ad-support, survey junk. My antivirus blocked this and I declined all the survey stuff and the program still worked. If you want to volunteer for it anyway, it will support the author of this useful tool.

Answer (score -1):

JPEG is not a working format.  It's a lossy format for final output.  You should never be working in JPEG, as your work will look rubbish.  I don't think Photoshop can even rotate JPEGs losslessly, due to the way that they are compressed in horizontal lines, with each pixel relating to the one that is linearly next to it (cannot think of better words to describe this at the moment).  More complex transformations would have an even worse result.

You working files should be in a lossless format, like TIFF for portability, but it makes most sense to use .psd if you are using Photoshop.

If you are working with files that were in .jpg format to begin with, save them as .psd before you start working with them.

When you need final output, for the web, email, etc, use the **Export function**, where you will get fine control of the compression level, with live previews.

If you really want to work against all sense, I think you should be able to easily save as JPEG from the Save As dialogue box by wrapping your filename in quotes, with the .jpg suffix (although I cannot test right now to make sure).  After the initial Save As, CTRL+S for Save will do.

eg.  `"Duh.jpg"`

Comment: ...this is the worst kind of "answer" on a site like this. Full of random opinion nobody asked for, ignores the original question, and ending with a dead-wrong halfassed suggestion. I'm not a professional photographer who is worried that the subtle shade of gray under someone's nostril will be lost in a crappy, grainy 12-quality jpeg that the average person could never differentiate from a tiff... I'm asking how to reorder a menu in a program. And btw, as "terrible" as it is, it's still the most widely used format.

Comment: @CreeDorofl:  It's not a personal opinion - it's a fact, which anybody that knows anything about graphics file formats will tell you.  I think `Export` is actually called `Save for Web` in Photoshop, but I do not have it in front of me right now.  That is what you should be using for making final output into lossy compressed formats.

Comment: Pretend I cared for a second about milking every ounce of quality out of my funny cat picture, while saving 15 KB of filesize. Let's say I use whatever format you personally approve of. How can manipulate a menu to put the preferred format at the top of the list, without recompiling the entire program? That's all I was asking. If I were wondering "what format should I be using for best quality and/or filesize?" then my question would be worded quite differently.

Comment: @CreeDorofl: I don't know why you would spend so much on a professional-grade graphics program for making lolcat pictures, but I think the file formats are actually plugins, which you can delete.  I have not tried this, and do not have Photoshop with me at the moment.  Look in the program folders.

Comment: @paradroid - Cheers, that does actually remove most of the unneeded options from the list. Sarcasm aside I don't disagree with any of what you're saying, and ctrl+alt+shift+S (aka save for web) is burned into my fingertips. It's just that on many sites I see a lot of "why would you want to do A? You should never do A, you should only do B". ...I do appreciate that despite my pissy replies you humored me with a fair suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @CreeDorofl: Okay, no problem, but if you are not dealing with photographs with continuous tones, and are working with line graphics, screenshots etc, you should be using .png (even .gif is better).  It's just my small effort to reduce retardation on the web, and I am quite drunk.

Comment: @paradroid By all means, the web could use less of it. I'm already quite fond of PNG because of the full alpha support. I'll make a point of using it more.